# Can't access `page` from react-table's useTable & usePagination

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-table, react-query

In the following code, I am trying to access the `page` property from the useTable & usePagination hook,

According to the docs, my implementation seems correct. but it keep saying that: `Property 'page' does not exist on type 'TableInstance<PipelinesData>'`

```
const tableData = useMemo(() => data, [data])
  const tableColumns = useMemo(() => columns, [columns])

  const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
      columns: tableColumns as any,
      data: tableData,
    },
    usePagination,
  )

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = tableInstance
```

Can you guys help me figuring out what I am doing wrong, thanks :)

Comment: witch version of react-table you are using ?

Comment: found the solution ser, it was a typescript error and it is happening due to the mismatch of the version number of the react table library & the @types file of the react-table library.